# Google+ JS API trigger the interactive post button automatically

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I'm using the Google+ API. I can render the 'Interactive Post' button with Javascript as described here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive#rendering_the_button_with_javascript

So, my code looks like this:

```
var options = {
    contenturl: myurl,
    clientid: myclientid,
    cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
    prefilltext: sometext,
    recipients: somerecipients,
    calltoactionlabel: 'View',
    calltoactionurl: myurl
};

gapi.interactivepost.render('gplus-share-trigger', options);
```

But I want to trigger the button automatically when it finished rendering, is it there any way to detect that? I dont want to do something ugly like:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('#gplus-share-trigger').click(); },500);
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to trigger the Share action without waiting for a user to click the button?

Comment: Yes, on my UI the user shares with drag and drop. So after dropping, for example, a picture on a friend, I'm running the code above but I still need to trigger the 'click' event when the button has finished rendering.

Comment: I believe the drop action of the drag-and-drop registers as an event, which could replace the click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
var options = {
    contenturl: myurl,
    clientid: myclientid,
    cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
    prefilltext: sometext,
    recipients: somerecipients,
    calltoactionlabel: 'View',
    calltoactionurl: myurl,
    callback: function(result) {
        $('#gplus-share-trigger').trigger("click");
    }
};
```

Comment: You should explain your code a bit. Point out how it is different from the code the OP has included in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Interactive posts don't have a callback function.

I have the same problem than Agustin and I had to implement a call inside a timeout.

Regards